# how to give a top level style to react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am wondering if there is any chance to give a style to our mobile app which all the pages use that if not over-written!

For example I want to use a special font and want to make sure all the following that font unless I define another font.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices!

1 : Use `react-native-global-props` npm package (good for something like default font - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-global-props))

2 : You can write a object with every key that you want and import this to everywhere! for example :

**Style.js**

```
export default const style= {
  bigMe: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
};
```

**RNComponent.js**

```
import stylefrom 'someAddress..'

class RNComponent extends Component {

// some code..

<Text style={style.bigMe}>Test!</Text>

// some code..

}
```